# Can I reset all packages to repo versions without ppa-purge?

Tags: package-management

This is just a theoretical for me (it's a real problem for another user) but let's say:

- I upgrade a load of packages from a PPA onto 12.04
- I upgrade to 14.04
- Some packages are held in because my PPA-upgraded packages have newer versions that are breaking dependencies

By this point I think it's too late for `ppa-purge` to be useful. Hypothetical-Oli should have run `ppa-purge` *before* the upgrade... But what's done is done. How do we turn this dependency deadlock into a working, updateable system?

Ideally we'd send everything with Ubuntu-repo versions back to those versions... But how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

- Ideally `ppa-purge` should work, as it is same procedure. PPA has always a version that is higher then both of `precise` and `trusty`.
- The only case I think of, is when dealing absolute packages or renamed ones (If a transient package is not provides).

  In this case, I would suggest:

  1. Add back all precise repositories.

     ```
     echo -e "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main universe multiverse restricted\ndeb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main universe multiverse restricted\ndeb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-update main universe multiverse restricted" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise.list
     ```
  2. Update package lists

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     ```
  3. Purge the PPA

     ```
     sudo ppa-purge ppa:...
     ```

     If didn't work try:

     ```
     sudo ppa-purge -d precise ppa:...
     ```

     You can try also `aptitude` which provides solutions with downgrade.

     Sometimes, manual fix is the only option.

     - You can use remove those package without their dependents, using

       ```
       sudo dpkg -r --force-depends ...
       ##disable ppa source then
       sudo apt-get -f install
       ```
     - Or force installing specific version from official repository. But you have to put all related packages in same command.

       ```
       sudo apt-get install pkg1=ver1 pkg2=ver2 ...
       ```
     - In the worst case you can download those packages with version from official repository and force install them using:

       ```
       sudo dpkg -i --force-depends ...
       ```

       AFAIK APT does not have away to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file (let's say `00_reset_ppas`) in folder `/etc/apt/preferences.d` with the following contents

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 1100
```

After that run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

and most (or even better all) packages from PPAs would be replaced from the standard ones that come with ubuntu, provided that there is no nanimg conflicts (ie packages with different names in ppas) that may introduce conflicts.